# Books on number theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I had a very short introduction to number theory in one of the classes I took and I learned a bit about divisibility and congruence, not much further than Fermat's little theorem, and I would like to learn more.

What's would be a good book that covers the basics and takes on a good level of depth, possibly with utmost rigorous proofs and a good variety of examples?

After that, what would be a bit more advanced titles?

Comment: I would recommend learning abstract algebra. [Maybe this link will be of use to you](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329/best-book-ever-on-number-theory?rq=1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good book to learn number theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350833/what-is-a-good-book-to-learn-number-theory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number Theory Reading List](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842996/number-theory-reading-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverman's *A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory* is a good text to start with, although it is very computational, but does go through basic ideas such as modular arithmetic and some basic diophantine equations.

Alternatively, Tattersall's *Elementary Number Theory in Nine Chapters* is available online: http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/Tattersall%20-%20Elementary%20number%20theory%20in%20nine%20chapters.pdf.  This doesn't cover quite as much stuff (for example quadratic reciprocity) but does go a bit more in depth and has plenty of proofs with it.

After that, if you like the algebra side of things, elliptic curves are done well in Silverman-Tate's *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* but you will need to have a reasonable understanding of abstract algebra for that (things like groups, fields etc). Elliptic curves are equations of the form $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ and have a strong connection to Fermat's Last Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of a comprehensive introduction, *Elementary Number Theory* by Underwood Dudley is a nice text with plenty of exercises and thorough proofs as far as I can tell. I am currently working through it and enjoy it very much. I can't speak much for more advanced texts, however.